# Django Vue.js - rendering multi-choice dropdown list

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I am trying to use Vue.js multiselect component:
https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Unfortunately it does not render as it should.
Instead of multiselect dropdown list, I am obtaining something like this:

[image]

Used code:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">open and close later
  </button>
    <pre>{{ isOpen }}</pre>
    <multiselect
        ref="multiselect"
        v-model="value"
        :options="options"
        :multiple="true"
        track-by="library"
        :custom-label="customLabel"
        @close="isOpen = false"
        @open="isOpen = true"
    >
  </multiselect>
</div>
```

Used libraries (included in ):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
```

Used script ( placed at the bottom of the page ):

```
<script>
        new Vue({
        components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
        },
        data: {
        isOpen: false,
        value: { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
        options: [
            {   language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue.js' },
          { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
          { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vuelidate' }
        ]
        },
      methods: {
        customLabel (option) {
          return `${option.library} - ${option.language}`
        },
        toggle () {
          this.$refs.multiselect.$el.focus()

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$refs.multiselect.$refs.search.blur()
          }, 400)
        }
      }
    }).$mount('#app')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Probably the most complete selecting solution for Vue.js 2.0, without
>   jQuery.

And you are using vue 1.0

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
```

So you need to change it to be v2

Also you need to look into console to see if there any errors and fix them